# Passing values from python to Rscript and vice-versa?

Tags: python, r, subprocess

I have built a regression model in R and want to use it in python.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("/usr/local/bin/Rscript --vanilla script.r", shell=True)
```

Above commands run the `R` script.

But I want to pass some values to the R script, which act as the input to the model. Also want to get back the model result. How can I do that?
I checked [rpy2](https://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/) module, but it didn't feel very dependable.

Comment: See: http://tuxette.nathalievilla.org/?p=1696, but `rpy2` is used by _scores_ of ppl who rely on it daily.